# i need to select a result from a sub query that gives multiple rows

Tags: sql, subquery

the sub query give multiple pids but i want to select the pid which has the min due date
the query i wrote is:

```
SELECT pid, 
       Min(duedate) 
FROM   job 
WHERE  ( pid ) = (SELECT pid 
                  FROM   job 
                  WHERE  job.pending = 'yes' 
                         AND ( pid ) = (SELECT pid 
                                        FROM   machinery_product_bridge 
                                        WHERE  mid = '2'))
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Edited after your comment

```
 select j.pid, min(j.duedate) 
 from job j
 where (j.pid) in (select j2.pid from job j2
            where j2.pending='yes' 
            and (j2.pid) in (select pid 
                            from machinery_product_bridge 
                            where mid='2'
                        )
            )
group by j.pid
```

Comment: Aggregate function MIN, but no GROUP BY? "= sub-select"?!?

Comment: it is still giving the same error that subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: that subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: This should not happen, we are using in clause. Re check your query.

Answer (score 0):

It better to use  Alias in sub query.I think You are looking for this

```
select pid, min(j.duedate) 
from job j where (j.pid) in (select jb.pid from job jb
where jb.pending='yes' and (jb.pid)=(select top 1 pid from machinery_product_bridge where mid='2')) 
group by j.PId
```

Comment: Why alias? He is not using joins. Justify.

Comment: Inner query does'nt know that Pid is from inner query Job table or outer query table  @PravinDeshmukh